# WKWebView not getting the correct language string from language.url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, wkwebview

I am loading an HTML file saved in a local file to WKWebView.

[image]

"measurements.html" is the file I am loading.
For loading the supporting css and js files, I set the read access url accordingly. See the following code.

```
NSString *filePath = @"../HTML/measurements.html"; //path of measurements.html
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

NSString *readAccessPath = @"../HTML"; //path of the HTML folder itself
NSURL *readAccessUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:readAccessPath];

[wkWebView loadFileURL:fileUrl allowingReadAccessToURL:readAccessUrl];
```

In the HTML file i have used some jQuery. All the images, css and js files mentioned in the "measurements.html" are loading and working correctly. But loading language url in DataTable was not working.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({

            "language": {
                "url": "supportfiles/js/DTNorwegian.js"
            }
});
```

If I set the content of DTNorwegian.js as the value for "language", it will work. Setting the url seems to make problem with WKWebView.
Loading the same html file to a UIWebView is working correctly.

Is there anything I am missing when implementing WKWebView? 
All the other functionalities are working, only issue is with language url setting.

Please help.

Comment: I could not find any solution for this. So I changed the HTML page implementation. Instead of setting the 'url' for language, i set the content of that js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DTNorwegian.js  file is a json file then You can hard code the content of DTNorwegian.js directly in to your code as the value of url property.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({

        "language": {
            "url": {
                // Paste the DTNorwegian.js code here

           }
        }
});
```

Hope it works , Cheers!!!!